# Shell metacharacters - A shorter way to match these types of filenames?

Tags: bash

For an exercise I wrote an expression consisting of meta-characters which match at most 3 uppercase characters.

Example

```
a -> match
A -> match
Ab -> match
AbC -> match
AbCd -> match 
...
ABCD -> no match, 4 uppercase chars
```

This is what I've come up with but I got a feeling I could make it shorter

```
ls @(!(*[A-Z]*)|*[A-Z]*|*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*|*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*)
```

**EDIT**

Sry for the confusion. First of all, I'm only allowed to use meta-characters, no regular expressions, no test, no tools like awk/sed/something else.
Moreover, the uppercase letters must not be consecutive.

**EDIT**

Okay, this one seems to work (but is even longer!).

```
export LC_COLLATE=C

ls @(!(*[A-Z]*)|!(*[A-Z]*)[A-Z]!(*[A-Z]*)|[A-Z]!(*[A-Z]*)[A-Z]!(*[A-Z]*)|!(*[A-Z]*)[A-Z]!(*[A-Z]*)[A-Z]!(*[A-Z]*)[A-Z]!(*[A-Z]*)
```

Comment: What about AbCDeFg?  In other words, do you mean consecutive or total uppercase characters?

Comment: You last one doesn't match **AbCD**.

Comment: Total uppercase letters.

Comment: What is the context of "only allowed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't work for me. One problem is that in many non-C locales `[A-Z]` includes some lowercase characters.

```
$ for c in a A b B z Z; do if [[ $c = [A-Z] ]]; then echo "match: $c"; else echo "no match: $c"; fi; done
no match: a
match: A
match: b
match: B
match: z
match: Z
```

Try it again with `LANG=C`. If you want to match only uppercase characters regardless of locale, use `[[:upper:]]`.

Another reason yours doesn't work is that parts of it always match.

For example:

```
!(*[A-Z]*)
```

(even if it's corrected using `[[:upper:]]`) matches (rejects) anything that consists of only uppercase characters regardless of length. However, the rest of the (partially corrected) pattern includes uppercase characters explicitly while including *any* character *including uppercase ones* implicitly because of the asterisks. So just the first part of that:

```
*[[:upper:]]*
```

says to include all strings that consist of at least one uppercase character *without regard* to how many more there may be: one, ten, a million.

Instead, try this:

```
if [[ $string != *[[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]* ]]
then
    echo "match: fewer than four uppercase character"
fi
```

It simply checks to see if there are four or more uppercase characters.

You could also use a regular expression (in Bash 3.2 or greater):

```
if [[ ! $string =~ ^.*[[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]].*$ ]]
then
    echo "match: fewer than four uppercase character"
fi
```

Another way is to delete all the non-uppercase characters and compare the difference in lengths.

Demo:

```
#!/bin/bash
strings[1]='AbCdEfghi'
strings[2]='ABCD'
strings[3]='Ab1Cd2Ef3ghi'
strings[4]='A1BbC2Dd'

for string in "${strings[@]}"
do
    test=${string//[^[:upper:]]}
    if (( ${#test} > 3 ))
    then
        echo "no match: $string"
    else
        echo "match: $string"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @Helper Method: My answer already contains the answer to your question. Here it is applied specifically to `ls`: `ls !(*[[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]*)` or `LC_COLLATE=C; ls !(*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*[A-Z]*))`. Note that `LC_COLLATE` doesn't need to be exported since it's the shell that is expanding the globbing and the only reason you'd need to export it for `ls` is to affect the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ls | grep -E '^([^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*){0,3}$'
```

Comment: I think that would fail on `a`, which is supposed to be a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "BCDAdf" | awk '{m=gsub(/[A-Z]/,"");print (m<4) ?"match":"no match"}'
no match

$ echo "CDAdf" | awk '{m=gsub(/[A-Z]/,"");print (m<4) ?"match":"no match"}'
match
```

Answer (score 0):

Erik mentioned using `grep`, so I'll use it too.

I think it should be:

```
/bin/ls -1 | grep -E '^[^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*)?)?)?$'
```

which can be shortened to:

```
/bin/ls -1 | grep -E '^[^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*){0,3}$'
```

---

If you really want to use `bash` extended patterns, it should look like this:

```
/bin/ls -1 *([^A-Z])?([A-Z]*([^A-Z]))?([A-Z]*([^A-Z]))?([A-Z]*([^A-Z]))
```

Note that you have to set `LC_COLLATE=C` for this to work.

---

If you want to write it shorter, you can use the fact that parameter expansion (i.e. variable expansion) happens before filename expansion, and do something bizarre like this:

```
u='[A-Z]' # $u == uppercase characters
U='[^A-Z]' # $U == non-uppercase characters
/bin/ls -1 *($U)?($u*($U))?($u*($U))?($u*($U))
```

Whether that's a good idea, I leave for you to decide. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this is correct:

```
!(*([^[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]*([^[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]*([^[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]*([^[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]*)
```

with extglob, of course.